# Django-tables2 - how can I get counts out in my table on a custom table field?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm trying to get some frequency data out from my queryset in a column in my table in django-tables2.

I am trying this via a custom field:

```
 class MyTable(tables.Table):

      custom_field = tables.Column(empty_values=())


      def render_custom_field(self):

           total_queryset = self.data.data

           # trying to get out the row object, to do a filter query something like:

           row_object = self.rows.instance
           
           freq = total_queryset.filter(myfield=row_object.myfield)

           return f"{len(freq)}/{len(total_queryset)}"
```

However I cannot get the row instance out to do this query. Does anyone know how I can get the row instance out to do this? (I'm also aware getting the total_queryset from self.data.data is probably a hacky way of doing this...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`record` is available as a direct argument, as well if your data is a QuerySet you can also use the `.count()` method.

```
def render_custom_field(self, record):
    return self.data.data.filter(myfield=record.myfield).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - you get the row instances from kwargs:

```
def render_custom_field(self, *args, **kwargs):

    total_queryset = self.data.data

    obj = kwargs['record']

    freq = total_queryset.filter(myfield=row_object.myfield)

    return len(freq)
```